# Equivalent of Clojure's "assoc-in" and "get-in" in Python

Tags: python, clojure

In Clojure you can update a map (dict) with `assoc-in` and create key path automatically if it don't exist.

```
(assoc-in {:a 1 :b 3} [:c :d] 33)
{:a 1, :c {:d 33}, :b 3}
```

Same for `get-in`: you can specify a path of keys (or list indices) and it will return the value specified by the path, `nil` if it does not exist.

```
(get-in {:a 1, :c {:d 33}, :b 3} [:c :d])
33
(get-in {:a 1, :c {:d 33}, :b 3} [:c :e])
nil
```

Is there a Python equivalent or a comparable shortcut out of the box? (yes, I know I can write dodgy dict wrappers myself, but I'd like to avoid it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def cdict():
...     return defaultdict(cdict)
... 
>>> d = cdict()
>>> d['a']=1
>>> d['b']=3
>>> d
defaultdict(<function cdict at 0x28d3ed8>, {'a': 1, 'b': 3})
>>> d['c']['d'] = 33
>>> d['c']['d']
33
>>> d
defaultdict(<function cdict at 0x28d3ed8>, {'a': 1, 'c': defaultdict(<function cdict at 0x28d3ed8>, {'e': defaultdict(<function cdict at 0x28d3ed8>, {}), 'd': 33}), 'b': 3})
>>> d['c']['e']
defaultdict(<function cdict at 0x28d3ed8>, {})
>>>
```

It returns an empty `cdict()` on key not found rather than `nil` or `None` but otherwise I think it behaves the same.

The `repr` could do with a bit of work!

Answer (score 3):

Or about this?

```
def assoc_in(dct, path, value):
    for x in path:
        prev, dct = dct, dct.setdefault(x, {})
    prev[x] = value

def get_in(dct, path):
    for x in path:
        prev, dct = dct, dct[x]
    return prev[x]


d = {}

assoc_in(d, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 33)
print d

x = get_in(d, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
print x
```